# CSS3 Animation not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get one div to rotate around another using CSS3 but for some reason it will not animate at all. I am using Chrome. Can anyone help?

here is the css

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#center {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 225px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}



@-webkit-keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-150px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-150px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-150px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-150px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

#small {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
    animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
}
```

and here is the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-webkit` prefix proprietary property to ensure that your animation runs in `Webkit` browsers

[You Need To Use Prefix For Webkit Browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SwRtQ/1/)

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#center {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 225px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}

@keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform:         rotate(0deg)
                           translate(-150px)
                           rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
                           translate(-150px)
                           rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:         rotate(360deg)
                           translate(-150px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
                           translate(-150px) 
                           rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rot {
    from {
          transform:        rotate(0deg)
                            translate(-150px)
                            rotate(0deg);
         -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
                            translate(-150px)
                            rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:          rotate(360deg)
                            translate(-150px) 
                            rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transform:  rotate(360deg)
                            translate(-150px) 
                            rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

#small {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
    animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 200px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 200px;
}
```

> Side Note: You should use proprietary properties of each browser i.e
>   `-moz`, `-webkit`, `-o` and `-ms` so that older versions of the
>   browser don't fail to animate

Comment: I think you can drop the `-ms-` prefix safely as IE10 already supports unprefixed CSS3 animations.

Comment: @Licson No we shouldn't, cuz not every user use the latest version

Comment: @MrAlien IE9 doesn't even support CSS3 animations.

Comment: @Licson I was not specific to animations, It supports few CSS3 properties if we've -ms prefixed properties :)